# Style-editable for selected box of text on webpage?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web, styled-components

I'm building a web app that should have a place to allow users to directly edit the style of the text area they selected
For example: [image]

When a user select a text area, a small box of style options need to appear on the top-bottom, and user can use it to change the style of selected area
Is it possible to do? or which keyword I should use to research for solution?
Thank you all

Comment: Rich text editors could help you with this. Check out i.e. CKEditor.